# how to give space between tr tag and divide by | in html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Hi in the below code how to give the space to two tr rows and i want to divide with this symbol.and background color should occupy the full table.first row no need this | i want to divide all the left side row with full | symbol and then right side td's

can any one help me

Expected output:

```
About Us    |   Latest News
Facilities      Events
Doctors         Gallery
Our Blogs       Contact Us
```

**html**

```
<div id="slider1">
<footer>
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
  <tr>
    <td>About Us</td>
    <td>Latest News</td>        

  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Facilities</td>
    <td>Events</td>     

  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Doctors</td>
    <td>Gallery</td>        

  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Our Blogs</td>
    <td>Contact Us</td>     

  </tr>
</table>

</footer>
</div>
```

**css**

```
#slider1 footer {
    background-color:#00008B;
    width:100%;

#footer tr {
    position: relative;
    list-style-type: none;
     display: inline;
    }
#footer tr:before {
    content: " | ";
}
#footer td {
    border: 1px dotted blue;
}
#footer tr.row2 td {
    padding-top: 40px;
}
#footer tr:first-child:before {
      content: none;
}
```

Comment: The text on the question and the expected output are unclear .

Comment: @DanielPinzon after the left side of the data I want to give space as well as it must divide with | symbol

Comment: @user.. see my answer.. is it what you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see this:  http://jsfiddle.net/ze0587d0/

```css
#slider1 footer {
   
    width:100%;
}
#footer tr {
    position: relative;
    list-style-type: none;
     display: inline;
    }
#footer tr:before {
    content: " | ";
}
#footer td {
    border: 1px dotted blue;
}
#footer tr.row2 td {
    padding-top: 40px;
}
#footer tr:first-child:before {
      content: none;
}
td{
    padding:5px;
}
     .border-right{
            
            border-right:1px solid #000;
        }
```

```html
<div id="slider1">
<footer>
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
  <tr>
    <td class='border-right'>About Us</td>
    <td>Latest News</td>        

  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Facilities</td>
    <td>Events</td>     

  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Doctors</td>
    <td>Gallery</td>        

  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Our Blogs</td>
    <td>Contact Us</td>     

  </tr>
</table>

</footer>
</div>
```

just add a class for the first td, where you want `|` sign, and the css `border-right:1px solid #000;`

**Edit:**

According to the comment by OP,

If you want all td's having a saperation with `|`, see this: http://jsfiddle.net/ze0587d0/2/

you need to add a border-right to all tds which are `first-child` of tr,

```
 tr td:first-child{

            border-right:1px solid #000;
        }
```

```css
#slider1 footer {
   
    width:100%;
}
#footer tr {
    position: relative;
    list-style-type: none;
     display: inline;
    }
#footer tr:before {
    content: " | ";
}
#footer td {
    border: 1px dotted blue;
}
#footer tr.row2 td {
    padding-top: 40px;
}
#footer tr:first-child:before {
      content: none;
}
     tr td:first-child{
            
            border-right:1px solid #000;
        }
td{
    padding:5px;
}
```

```html
<div id="slider1">
<footer>
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
  <tr>
    <td >About Us</td>
    <td>Latest News</td>        

  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Facilities</td>
    <td>Events</td>     

  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Doctors</td>
    <td>Gallery</td>        

  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Our Blogs</td>
    <td>Contact Us</td>     

  </tr>
</table>

</footer>
</div>
```

Comment: I want to give space beween 1st side of the content and 2nd side of the content with this symbol it will come upto our Blogs and contact us

Comment: @user thats what my answer does?

Comment: how to increase the | height

Comment: Add paddingtop and padding bottom to td.. It will imcrease the height

Comment: Ok so you want all tds to divide the tr

Comment: yes exactly I am looking like this.thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you are after...it uses your pseudo-element but positions it absolutely.

```css
#slider1 footer {
  background-color: #00008B;
  width: 100%;
  color: white;
}
#slider1 table {
  table-layout: fixed;
}
#slider1 footer tr td {
  padding: 0 1rem;
  position: relative;
}
#slider1 footer tr:first-of-type td:first-child:after {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  content: "|";
}
```

```html
<div id="slider1">
  <footer>
    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
      <tr>
        <td>About Us</td>
        <td>Latest News</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Facilities</td>
        <td>Events</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Doctors</td>
        <td>Gallery</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Our Blogs</td>
        <td>Contact Us</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </footer>
</div>
```